# WCF REST. Is it possible to log the requests that were received from the client to the Database?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am new to WCF. I have a WCF REST service that implments the ServiceAuthorizationManager. The requirement is to log the request received from the clients to a table in the DB. Where should this happen, I mean in the AuthorizationManager that implements ServiceAuthorizationManager? and how to gather all the info like the IP Address of the client, the auth headers passed by the client so that I can populate an object and make a db call in the Application_EndRequest of Global.asax class.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Raju

Comment: are you hosting the service in IIS?

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding a message inspector to your service. I found this link that might be helpful:
[WCF REST Message Inspector](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WCF-REST-Message-Inspector-c4b6790b)

In the `AfterReceiveRequest` method you can extract header information etc. from the request header.

Implement your logic in `BeforeSendReply` instead of in `Application_EndRequest`.

Comment: I'm not finding that AfterReceiveRequest is adequate.  I'm getting an error parsing the faults in the returned message and this is happening before AfterReceiveRequest is called - making this useless for actual troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're hosting your service in IIS 7+, an easier way would be to setup AppFabric and enable end-to-end monitoring for that service rather than rolling your own. [Here's a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2011/03/23/appfabric-wcf-http-service-template.aspx) that shows a sample service and the config required to get this working.

If you decide to go the ServiceAuthorizationManager route, [check out this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.serviceauthorizationmanager.aspx) on using that class. It shows how to override the CheckAccessCore method and retrieve the message headers, etc. This is where you could implement the call to log the request if authorization succeeds.